# Ошибка при компиляции .c в .exe

Tags: c, gcc, компиляция, windows-10, exe

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста. При компиляции из .c в .exe через gcc вылетает ошибка. 
И правильно ли прописана переменная Path?
Подробности на скринах.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так файл `libmingwex-0.dll` находится в папке `C:\MinGW\bin`?

Comment: Мне почему-то кажется, что он в `\lib\ ` будет.

Comment: А какой IDE используете?

Answer (score 1):

Уменя буквально только что возникла такая же проблема. После гугления наткнулся на страницу: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/news/2017/02/mingwrt-50-and-w32api-50-snapshots-available/
Доустановил пакет mingw32-libmingwex dev (и ниже ... dll автоматом выбрался) (см скриншот). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Проблема разрешилась.